# Ignore lines in a XML file

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have two options to load one XML file. In the first one I use a local XML file and I can load the file with no problems but in the second one I use a XML file that I obtain from a web service and the format differs in the first two lines and I can´t load the file.

the files looks like this:

Local file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
...Here goes the content
```

Web service file:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<string xmlns="http://direcction/here/">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
...Here goes the content
```

So when I load the XML how can I ignore the "This XML file..." line and the `<string>` tag? because I think that is the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you source you're downloading the file and not the "source page" as rendered when you "open" an xml file in a browser ?

Comment: @Sehnsucht Yes I'm downloading the file.

Comment: That's not a valid XML file...